# concatenate and Format italic to 1 cell only. in google sheet

Tags: concatenation, google-sheets-formula, italic

=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1
here is my formula.

I want C1 to be italic in the result

i want to include the italic formula while concatenating multiple cell.

I also considering to use google app script if but i don't know the right formula. My result always return to all data is italic.